# leafleat-editable.js with mapbox.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, mapbox

I am trying to integrate `leafleat.editable.js` and `mapbox.js` togather.
But it throws error.

The error is:

`TypeError: L.Evented is undefined on leafleat.editable.js line 21`

I have downloaded example from [here](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.Editable) and included `mapbox.js` in it.

It works fine if I remove `mapbox.js`

Are both the plugins compatible with each other? If yes, please help me with the error.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As the Leaflet.Editable page advises:

> WARNING: the gh-pages branch needs latest Leaflet master (future 1.0).
>   To use the stable Leaflet release, please use the leaflet0.7 branch.

Mapbox.js is currently built on Leaflet 0.7, so you should be sure to use the version of Leaflet.Editable from the [leaflet0.7 branch](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.Editable/tree/leaflet0.7). Here is an example using mapbox with an editable control:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/nathansnider/jzrjpoaa/

This appears to work fine, though of course there may be other things that do not behave as expected. For instance, I did need to include leaflet.css in order for the edit button to show the line icon as intended, since the editable plugin apparently relies on some Leaflet styles that are not included in Mapbox.